# How to make Room DB insertion faster?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, android-lifecycle, rx-android

I am inserting only 1000 object into Room Database using Rx-Android but it is taking at-least 7 minutes. How can I make it faster?

I am using retrofit to fetch data from server with paging and using zip operator of RxJava to fetch them in parallel. I am getting all the data within 24 seconds but while I am inserting them into Room DB, it is taking atleast 7 minutes to insert them and sometimes taking more than 10 minutes.
I have tried to insert all 1000 objects together, by 100 and also one by one but getting the same result each time. I have read some article regarding insertion delay and found it takes upto 64 sec for 1000 object.

GroupA entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "group_a")
public class GroupA {

    @Expose
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String _id;
    @Expose
    @TypeConverters(AbracketseConverter.class)
    private List<Abracketse> abracketses;
    @Expose
    private String createdate;
    @Expose
    private String group;
    @Expose
    private String headercolumna;
    @Expose
    private String headercolumnb;
    @Expose
    @TypeConverters(StringConverter.class)
    private List<String> morelist;
    @Expose
    private Long sequence;
    @Expose
    private String subheader;
    @Expose
    private String updatedate;
}
```

Abracketse

```
public class Abracketse {

    @Expose
    private String columna;
    @Expose
    private String columnb;
    @Expose
    private String columnc;
    @Expose
    private String columnd;
    @Expose
    private String columne;
    @Expose
    private String columnf;
    @Expose
    private String columng;
}
```

Room database

```
@Database(entities = {
        RecentSearchModel.class,
        Calculator.class,
        GroupA.class,
        GroupB.class
}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract SearchDAO searchDAO();
    public abstract CalculatorDAO calculatorDAO();
    public abstract GroupADAO groupADAO();
    public abstract GroupBDAO groupBDAO();

}
```

GroupA DAO

```
@Dao
public interface GroupADAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Completable insertAllGroupA(List<GroupA> groupAList);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertGroupA(GroupA groupA);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM group_a")
    Single<List<GroupA>> getAllGroupA();

}
```

Room instance from Application class

```
public static MyRoomDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (DB_INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (MyRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (DB_INSTANCE == null) {
                    DB_INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                            MyRoomDatabase.class, "my_database")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return DB_INSTANCE;
    }
```

Fetching data from server and merging them

```
 APIs apIs = RetroCliet.getClient();
        List<Observable<List<GroupA>>> observableRequestList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            observableRequestList.add(apIs.getGroupAMedicineList(new MedDataFetchBody(i)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
        }
        List<GroupA> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Observable<List<GroupA>> result = Observable.zip(observableRequestList, objects -> {
            for (Object object : objects) {
                for (Object childObject : (List<GroupA>) object) {
                    result1.add((GroupA) childObject);

                }
            }
            return result1;
        });

        result.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new Observer<List<GroupA>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable.add(d);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<GroupA> groupAS) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        CustomDialog.dismissDialog();
                        reTryDialouge();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        insertToDB(result1);
                    }
                });
```

Inserting data to Room

```
 Completable.fromAction(() -> MyApplication.getDatabase().groupADAO().insertAllGroupA(groupAS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable.add(d);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        CustomDialog.dismissDialog();
                    }
                }));
```

Where is my fault? How can I improve it? How can I faster the insertion operation?

Comment: how do you calculate inserting time?

Comment: I have put debugger in the insertion method and in library class method, then I have used stop clock to measure the time. I know its not the actual way but this is how I could get an assumption on required time. This insane level of time to insert is not likely. There must be something that I have made wrong. Please help if you can.

Comment: Another thing is, I have used Realm with this same codebase and worked like a charm, inserted all the data within 1.5 minutes and this time, I have inserted 14000 data object.